# need to refresh page after axios call

Tags: reactjs, axios

As the title states, I need to refresh the page after an axios call function, but not before the promise has been received. The page is currently refreshing after the function fires but the promise is not received . What I am trying to do is to submit a blog post to the api, When I add the preventDefault function at the end everything works as it should.

here function:

```
handleSubmit(event){
    axios.post("https://saulvegablog.devcamp.space/portfolio/portfolio_blogs", this.buildForm(), {withCredentials:true})
    .then(response => {
      this.props.handleSuccessfullFormSubmission(response.data);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("handlesubmit error for blog ", error)
    })
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: So, is there a question/issue here? Are you asking why adding `event.preventDefault()` fixed your form reloading the page upon submission? By 'refresh page' do you mean react's state/props update somewhere and react rerenders the UI, or an actual page reload?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can reload your page in `then` callback function by adding

```
window.location.reload()
```

like this

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post("https://saulvegablog.devcamp.space/portfolio/portfolio_blogs", this.buildForm(), {withCredentials:true})
    .then(response => {
      this.props.handleSuccessfullFormSubmission(response.data);
      window.location.reload();
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("handlesubmit error for blog ", error)
    })
}
```

Comment: I want all pages to reload, right now only the vuejs page gets reloaded.